# LSTM - How can I prevent dirfferent loss / R2 outcomes for the same input?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm

I have a LSTM neural Network in python (kears) I want to use tp predict some time series Data.

The Problem i have is that i always get different loss and r2 (degree of determination) values, sometimes even NaN as loss, although i don't change the code at all

I tried to use different loss functions (mse, mae). I also tried to change layers or the size of my sequence, Nothing worked.

```py
changes = Bedarf_data[["Bedarf_changes", "Temperatur_changes", "monat", "uhrzeit"]].values

X = []
Y = []

for i in range (0, len(changes) - 96):
    Y.append(changes[i,0])
    X.append(np.array(changes[i+1:i+97]))

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 96, 4)
Y = np.array(Y)

# Modell
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(12, activation="relu", input_shape=(96, 4)))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="mse")
model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=96, epochs=10)
```

I expected at least a stable Outcome without too much Variation.
What can I do to get at least a stable Output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neural networks use a lot of random initialization. This means that every time you create a new net, it's different from the others.

You can set a random seed (but you need to reset the kernel entirely before every run) to guarantee that the random numbers will always be the same:

```
numpy.random.seed(choose_a_number)
```

You may also try `tf.set_random_seed(choose_a_number)`

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Is it relevant where i insert that line? (Beginner here)

Comment: Yes, it must be before the first random thing. (Usually everyone puts it right after importing numpy)